# Regex for taking only the domain name

Tags: c#, regex

I have this list of domains

```
https://download.my-domain.com/auth/login
https://download.my-domain.com
http://localhost:60162/API/script/authbar.js
http://localhost:28173/logout.aspx
http://my-domain.com/logout.aspx
http://my-domain.com/logout.aspx/
http://my-domain.com/
http://my-domain.com
http://my-domain.tk/
http://my-domain.gov
download.my-domain.com/auth/login
www.download.my-domain.com/auth/login
http://www.google.com
https://www.google.com
http://www.google.com/
https://www.google.com/
```

and i tried

```
((\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}))/?
```

but it also detects the **logout.aspx** any help would be appreciated..

TYIA

**Expected Result:**

> my-domain.com
>
> localhost (without the port)
>
> google.com
>
> my-domain.tk
>
> my-domain.gov

**Usage:**

> For cookie domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might work for you:

```
[-a-z0-9_]+(?!://)(?:\.[-a-z0-9_]+)?(?=[/:]|$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[JS Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gA2gB1)

[C# Demo](http://rextester.com/TOC41625)

Comment: yeah.. it does work but it includes the subdomain.. amazing.. it has a graph.. how did you generate it anyway if its ok if i ask? :)

Comment: @VincentDagpin Sorry, missed that point, just a moment.

Comment: @VincentDagpin The image is generated by https://debuggex.com/

Answer (score 1):

maybe this one is more likely to work in your example

```
([a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.(com|net|org|info|coop|co\.uk|org\.uk|ac\.uk|uk|tk|gov)))|localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this with minimum regular expression in Javascript because I was bored. I imagine it would be pretty easy to convert to c#?

```
var urls = [
  'https://download.my-domain.com/auth/login',
  'https://download.my-domain.com',
  'http://localhost:60162/API/script/authbar.js',
  'http://localhost:28173/logout.aspx',
  'http://my-domain.com/logout.aspx',
  'http://my-domain.com/logout.aspx/',
  'http://my-domain.com/',
  'http://my-domain.com',
  'http://my-domain.tk/',
  'http://my-domain.gov',
  'download.my-domain.com/auth/login',
  'www.download.my-domain.com/auth/login',
  'http://www.google.com',
  'https://www.google.com',
  'http://www.google.com/',
  'https://www.google.com/'
];

var domains = urls.map(function (url) {
  var domain = url.replace(/^https?:\/\//, '').split('/')[0];

  if (domain.indexOf(':') > 0) {
    domain = domain.split(':')[0];
  } else {
    domain = domain.split('.').slice(-2).join('.');
  }

  return domain;
});
```

Comment: i added some syntax in C# from your answer. i cant add it in comment because it's too long.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
((\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}))/?
```

You should add all possible top level domain

```
((\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.(com|net|org|info|coop|co\.uk|org\.uk|ac\.uk|uk|tk)/?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Regex("^(?>https?://|)([-A-Z0-9+&@#%?=~_|!,.;]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

if you want to ignore lines ending in logout.aspx, then try the following:

```
Regex("^(?>https?://|)([-A-Z0-9+&@#%?=~_|!,.;]+)[-A-Z0-9+&@#%?=~_|!,:/.;]*(?<!logout.aspx/?)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```